# Direct3D acceleration in VMware workstation

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

I would like to virtualize Blizzard's Direct3D game - SC2. Is it ok to do it on a Linux host or do I have to change it to Windows 7? Are there some significant performance differences in Direct3D virtualization in general, regarding the host OS ?

Comment: Not appropriate for this site but yes of course there's huge performance impacts when using Direct3D in a VM, you'll see a fraction of the native performance.

Comment: If VMWare’s DX virtualization does not perform well enough (and for StarCraft 2, I can’t imagine that it would), try VirtualBox; it also has DX virt., though I would assume that wouldn’t perform as well as on a physical system either.

Answer (score 1):

I sucessfully virtualized the Direct3D with vmware workstation, performance was good. The tricky part is:

- disconnecting mouse and keyboard from the host by clicking the icons on the right side of the status bar
- disable the feature, which enables console window to lost focus if the mouse pointer moves out of its edges

Performance in Ubuntu Linux was sufficient but in Windows 7 was 10 times better although with lots of graphics artefacts.